# Enable inbuild HTTP endpoint for AWS lambda

Tags: aws-sam

I am writing AWS SAM application which has a step function and a lambda function. Lambda function is responsible for invoking the step function.

Since call to step function takes more than 29 seconds to complete - I cannot use API Gateway. Lambda has 15 minutes timeout limit - my call will take 30-40 seconds to complete.

I want to use [inbuild HTTP endpoint of Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/) to be invoked from my frontend application -

1. How can I add HTTP endpoint to my lambda (initially it is okay if it is public with no AUTH)
2. What authentication I can add to lambda endpoint, so that only frontend application (running as node application) can invoke it? I want this to be POST call with multiple parameters passed via request body.

My `template.yaml` file is:

```
InvokeStateMachineFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      FunctionName: !Sub invoke-state-machine-${Stage}
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 300 # 5 minutes
      CodeUri: functions/invoke_step_function/
      Role: !GetAtt InvokeStateMachineFunctionRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          MY_SF_ARN: !GetAtt MyStateMachine.Arn

InvokeStateMachineFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub invoke-state-machine-${Stage}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: startSyncExecution
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - states:StartSyncExecution
                Resource: !Ref MyStateMachine
        - PolicyName: functionURLAllowPublicAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Sid: FunctionURLAllowPublicAccess
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl
                Resource: arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-number>:function:invoke-state-machine-SAND
                Condition:
                  StringEquals:
                    lambda:FunctionUrlAuthType: NONE
```

This code doesn't seem to make the Lambda URL public.

`Error: {"Message":"Forbidden"}`

My last option is to do it manually via AWS console -

[image: Resource based Lambda policy]

Need help in finding the correct way to achieve HTTP URL in lambda via `template.yaml`